# Join in Django with Foreing Key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using in-built User Model. Now i want to display in my template `first_name`, `last_name` form `User` Model and `timesheet_is_running` from `TimesheetEntry` Model.

Models.py

```
class TimesheetEntry(models.Model):
    timesheet_users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_users')
    timesheet_is_running = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "timesheet_entry"
```

View.py

```
class ClockInOutUserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'admin/clock/clock.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
        context = super(ClockInOutUserListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        company_name = self.request.user.userprofile.user_company
        context['users'] = User.objects.exclude(
            Q(userprofile__user_is_deleted = True) |
            Q(userprofile__user_company__company_is_deleted=True) | 
            Q(userprofile__user_role__acl_role_title='Admin')
            ).filter(
                Q(userprofile__user_company =company_name) 
            )
        #for user in context['users']:
            # job_user = TimesheetEntry.objects.get(timesheet_users=user)
            #print(user.timesheet_entry_set.all())

        return context
```

For displaying i am using `get_context_data` in which `context['users']` is printing my users `first_name` and `last_name`. But i am not able to display `timesheet_is_running` which is in `Jobs` Model. So i was thinking about `join`.

Please help to join two Models `User` and `TimesheetEntry` so that i can display in my template

template.html

```
{% for user in users %}
  {{user.first_name}}
  {{user.last_name}}
  {{user.timesheet_is_running}} <!-- How can get this value in template -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That value is on TimesheetEntry. You have *many* TimesheetEntry instances per User. Which one do you want to show for a user?

Comment: the user who is going to have True value in field `timesheet_is_running`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I'm not asking which users, I'm asking which timesheetentries for each user?

Comment: This is working for me `for user in context['users']: user.timesheet_users.last()` but i want to put this in context

Comment: You don't need to put it in the context, you can do it in the template.

Comment: yeah i got it thanks `{{user.timesheet_users.last.timesheet_is_running}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your user has only one entry than you can add it directly in template(as was mentioned in comments). For this you can do:

```
{% for user in users %}
  {{user.first_name}}
  {{user.last_name}}
  {{user.timesheet_users.last.timesheet_is_running}}
{% endfor %}
```

or if you have multiple timesheet entries than you can just iterate through all of them also in the template:

```
{% for user in users %}
  {{user.first_name}}
  {{user.last_name}}
  {% for entry in user.timesheet_is_running.all %}
     {{entry.timesheet_is_running}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```